# Is there a widely used service to report bike theft?

Tags: theft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are bicycle registration websites any use for recovering stolen bikes?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4319/are-bicycle-registration-websites-any-use-for-recovering-stolen-bikes)

Or to say, a website where stolen bikes could be reported and anyone could check if for reports of a given brand/model or serial number.

I don't mean a police report. A mean an open service with data accesible to any user.